# Sublime Text 3 file preview opening a new tab when it should not

Tags: sublimetext3

Hope someone can help me with this:

I just upgraded from Sublime Text 2, to 3. Now, when I single click on a file to just preview its contents, it actually opens a new tab that must be closed by clicking the "x" on the tab. From my research, this has to do with the setting

```
// Preview file contents when clicking on a file in the side bar. Double
// clicking or editing the preview will open the file and assign it a tab.
"preview_on_click": true,
```

As the default states, it should just preview the file on single click, but it actually opens it. I did copy the setting into my user preferences file as is, but it had no effect. As an experiment, I set it to :false in my user preferences, and it would not open the file on single click, but it wouldn't preview it either. What am I missing??

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a fix?